# How to create die line from shape for printing purposes

Tags: uv

There's a serious problem im dealing with for over few last years. I'm not a "pro" blender user, i don't need to be. I'm using blender mainly for creating less or more simple POS materials.

But i always have a problem like below.

[image]

I need to create something like on white background from the shape seen above it. Unwrapped both sides of this "altar".

How to do it? Standard unwrapping doesn't work for me (or i don't know how to do it).

Comment: Really? No-one?